# Simplify If statement C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate a count for values coming in from a database call. I am using an if statement to go through each value. I am a newbie to programming and I can help feeling that there is a shorter way to do this, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

This is my data call:

```
public List<MarkingOverviewDTO> GetMarkingOverview(int? myModuleID)
{
    List<MarkingOverviewDTO> MyMarkingOverview = new List<MarkingOverviewDTO>();

    using (var context = new StudentPortalDBEntities1())
    {
        var myOverview =
            from m in context.ModuleDetails
            join ms in context.MarkingScheduleOverviews on m.ModuleID equals ms.ModuleFk
            join mot in context.MarkingOverviewTitles on ms.MSOverview equals mot.OverviewTitleID
            where m.ModuleID == myModuleID
            select new
            {
                mot.TitleName,
                ms.Comment1,
                ms.Comment2,
                ms.Comment3,
                ms.Comment4,
                ms.Comment5,
                ms.Comment6,
                ms.Comment7,
                ms.Comment8,
                ms.Comment9,
                ms.Comment10,

            };

        foreach (var item in myOverview)
        {
            MyMarkingOverview.Add(new MarkingOverviewDTO
            {
                OverviewTitle = item.TitleName,
                Comment1 = item.Comment1,
                Comment2 = item.Comment2,
                Comment3 = item.Comment3,
                Comment4 = item.Comment4,
                Comment5 = item.Comment5,
                Comment6 = item.Comment6,
                Comment7 = item.Comment7,
                Comment8 = item.Comment8,
                Comment9 = item.Comment9,
                Comment10 = item.Comment10,
                //Get the comment count to generate the correct number of checkboxes per row
                MyCommentCount = CountComments(item.Comment1, item.Comment2, item.Comment3, item.Comment4, item.Comment5, item.Comment6, item.Comment7, item.Comment8, item.Comment9, item.Comment10),
            });
        }
    }

    return MyMarkingOverview;
}
```

This is my method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get comment count based on value. This will return a count to generate the correct number of check boxes  per overview
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Comment1"></param>
/// <param name="Comment2"></param>
/// <param name="Comment3"></param>
/// <param name="Comment4"></param>
/// <param name="Comment5"></param>
/// <param name="Comment6"></param>
/// <param name="Comment7"></param>
/// <param name="Comment8"></param>
/// <param name="Comment9"></param>
/// <param name="Comment10"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int CountComments(string Comment1, string Comment2, string Comment3, string Comment4, string Comment5, string Comment6, string Comment7, string Comment8, string Comment9, string Comment10)
{
    var myCommentCount = 0;

    if (Comment1 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment2 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment3 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment4 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment5 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment6 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment7 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment8 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment9 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    if (Comment10 != null)
    {
        myCommentCount += 1;
    }

    return myCommentCount;
}
```

Comment: Put all the comments in an array, then do `Count(x => x != null)`. You could probably refactor this better.

Comment: If you give `CountComments` a `params` array, you can loop over it there, and you don't even have to change the calling context. But I find this whole "let's have 10 fields of something" highly suspicious anyway, do you really need it? Why isn't an array/list/whatever?

Comment: @harold: Seeing we thinking the same, I just made an answer :)

Comment: It looks like you have a database schema problem. I'd recommend fixing the schema first and foremost. Have a "Comments" table, then you can have 1, or 10, or 1000 comments, and you can get all of the comments with a simple join.

Comment: @harold: Thanks for the input. If I understand you correctly I need to add a comment table to my database so all comments will be in one column. At the moment all my comments are in a row under column, comment 1, comment 2 etc. There will never be more than 10 comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public int CountComments(params string[] comments)
{
  return comments.Count(x => x != null);
}
```

Comment: Even better than an array. Good solution.

Comment: I would change `!= null` with `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I wouldn't as that conflicts with the OPs original code.

Comment: Since OP is newbie, you can also show how to call this method.

Comment: @ArghyaC nothing to change in the actual call

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer What you believe and what is actually happening may not be the same thing. Let OP decide that.

Comment: @Steve I mean different options, but yes, for now it'll work for him.

Comment: @DavidG You're argument is valid, BTW when you check if a string is not null, usually you do it to check if the property has content or not... but well, let's see what OP says ;D

Comment: Also, I would add a code contract: `Contract.Requires(comments != null && comments.length > 0)`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That entirely depends on the situation. Something being empty may be a valid response and completely different than null.

Comment: First up, you guys rock! Thanks for the solution, this worked. Still have heaps to learn I know. this is my first year of programming :)